# Почему Docker не добавляет в имидж сабдиректорий?

Tags: docker

У меня есть Docker file
Вот он:

```
FROM python:3.10-slim-buster
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install build-essential -y

RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . ./

CMD gunicorn  -b :$PORT --chdir=app main:app -w 1 -t 8 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --timeout 60
```

И есть простой деплоймент скрипт.

Я билджу имидж и пушу его на GCP, а потом на основании имиджа создаю сервис.
После деплоя имиджа я вижу, что у меня нету контента сабфолдеров - только файлы внутри них.

Вот структура:

```
app: 
 Config.py
 ...
 data.py 

frontend: 
 build 
 public 
 README.md
```

....

Поскольку в директории `app` есть только файлы то здесь все хорошо - все файлы я вижу.
Но, в директории frontend я вижу только файлы, но директорий и их контента не вижу. Т. е. директорий `build` и `public` - нет.
`build` и `public` нету в файле `.gitignore`, т. е. они должны существовать и имидже.

Почему так происходит?
И как это можно исправить?
Благодарю

Comment: Что-то удивительное вы рассказываете. `COPY` копирует рекурсивно. Как вы проверили, что у вас нет `frontend/public` и `frontend/build`? Что выводит команда `docker run --rm <ваш_образ> ls -lR /code`?

Comment: @PakUula прошу прощения, разобрался с вопросом - моя ошибка была